# Cups not core dumping

Tags: cups, core-dump

Even though core dumping is enabled on my system and is working for every other processes, cups is setting its soft limit to 0 over-ridding the system defaults.  I've yet to find documentation on how to override this and i'm digging through the cups source now to find where it is setting it.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So cups apparently disables the ability to core dump after looking at the source code.  To properly generate a core dump one must use the Automatic Bug Reporting Tool (ABRT).  Once setup it will generate the required core dump your looking for.